# Cloud Pub/Sub Demo : 403 User not authorized to perform this action. when try to push notification

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am learning Google Cloud Pub/Sub and following this official document : [Writing and Responding to Pub/Sub Messages - Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/writing-and-responding-to-pub-sub-messages#prerequisites)

When I deploy it to cloud, and try to submit the message, 
[image]
I get the following error :

> An internal error occurred:
>   403 User not authorized to perform this action. (POST https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/your-project-id/topics/your-topic:publish)
>   See logs for full stacktrace.

I guess it's due to some authentication problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Make sure that the client you are using is authorized to publish to Pub/Sub. See [details here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/access_control). If your client belongs to the same project as the topic, typically it won't require additional access control configuration. Make sure that your client is [authenticated properly](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/configure#auth).

Answer (score 11):

Here are some notes come from google's documentation [Troubleshooting 403 (Forbidden) error](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/troubleshooting#403) :

> If you get this error, do the following:
>
> - Make sure you've enabled the Google Cloud Pub/Sub API in the Cloud    Platform Console.
> - Make sure that the principal making the request has the required    permissions on the relevant Google Cloud Pub/Sub resources,
>     especially if you are using Google Cloud Pub/Sub for cross-project
>     communication.
> - If you're using Dataflow, make sure that both    @cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com and the Compute Engine
>     Service account -compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
>     have the required permissions on the relevant Google Cloud Pub/Sub
>     resource. See Google Cloud Dataflow Security and Permissions for more 
>     information.
> - If you're using App Engine, check your project's Permissions page to    see if an App Engine Service Account listed as an Editor. If it
>     is    not, add your App Engine Service Account as an Editor. Normally,
>     the    App Engine Service Account is of the form
>     @appspot.gserviceaccount.com.

Answer (score 7):

In view of subscription and topic you can click "permission" -> "add principal", paste long e-mail from your json with service account and select permissions described in

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Latest python demo works, but ruby API needed `viewer` permission

The python demo shown in episode 3 of Google video series [#pubsubmadeeasy](https://www.youtube.com/hashtag/pubsubmadeeasy)
[Cloud Pub/Sub in Action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5DOsB7Nlw0&t=1s) worked fine with updated code (see notes below) using the permissions the videos instructed you to add, specifically

```
Pub/Sub Publisher
Pub/Sub Subscriber
```

But switching over to the [ruby API](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-pubsub/latest/index.html) required adding the viewer permission to the service account created in the demo. Note: using ruby `3.1.0` and `gem 'google-cloud-pubsub', '~> 2.9', '>= 2.9.1'`.

```
Pub/Sub Viewer
```

#### Notes on python sample setup:

- Using python 3.10.1
- Sample code
  `https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub.git`
  specifically
  `https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/tree/main/samples/snippets/quickstart`

```
virtualenv venv && source venv/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-pubsub
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=downloaded_key.json 
export PROJECT=`gcloud config get-value project`
```

### Error Examples:

#### subscribe error

```
/home/dever/.gem/ruby/3.1.0/gems/google-cloud-pubsub-v1-0.6.2/lib/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/subscriber/client.rb:499:
in `rescue in get_subscription':
 7:User not authorized to perform this action.. debug_error_string:
{"created":"@1642638738.357361477",
"description":"Error received from peer ipv6:[2607:f8b0:4006:80a::200a]:443",
"file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1063,
"grpc_message":"User not authorized to perform this action.","grpc_status":7} 
(Google::Cloud::PermissionDeniedError)
```

#### publish error

```
/home/dever/.gem/ruby/3.1.0/gems/google-cloud-pubsub-v1-0.6.2/lib/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/publisher/client.rb:574:
in `rescue in get_topic': 
7:User not authorized to perform this action.. 
debug_error_string:{"created":"@1642638676.763569110",
"description":"Error received from peer ipv6:[2607:f8b0:4006:80a::200a]:443",
"file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1063,
"grpc_message":"User not authorized to perform this action.","grpc_status":7} 
(Google::Cloud::PermissionDeniedError)
```

Comment: strange, but thanks for the answer :)