# Publish Pub/Sub messages from APP script: PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I was following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@jankrynauw/google-pub-sub-cron-job-using-google-apps-script-ef218626218d) to make a sheet that publishes rows as messages to Pub/Sub topic.

However, I got this error:

```json
{ 
  error: {
    code: 403,
    message: 'User not authorized to perform this action.',
    status: 'PERMISSION_DENIED' 
  } 
}
```

What might be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by multiple accounts.

I created the spreadsheet and applied permissions with my usual account, and that account doesnot have access to the GCP project.

After re-create the spreadsheet with my dev account, which own the GCP project, everything worked!

Answer (score 0):

Authentication problem seems to be the cause

Please go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37623509/cloud-pub-sub-demo-403-user-not-authorized-to-perform-this-action-when-try-to#:%7E:text=Make%20sure%20that%20your%20client%20is%20authenticated%20properly.&text=Here%20are%20some%20notes%20come,in%20the%20Cloud%20Platform%20Console.) link , this might help you to resolve the issue.